# Pkgdef error when publishing VSIX to VS Marketplace

Tags: c#, visual-studio, publish, vsix

I've create a solution template. When installing the VSIX package locally everything works fine but when trying to upload/publish my VSIX file to VS Marketplace I'm getting this error: VSIX packages of type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectTemplate' cannot include .pkgdef files.

How can I exclude the pkgdef file from the VSIX package so I can get rid of this error.

Comment: A .pkgdef file is not required for a template. How exactly is this .pkgdef included in your .VSIX project, and what does it do? Is the .pkgdef a part of the templatized solution/project? How is it referenced/included in  your .csproj file?

Comment: I have also the same issue.